# Two problems with my query: Show null values and order by before group by

Tags: sql, group-by, left-join, sql-order-by

I'm having major problems with my query.  I want to show all results in the source table even if there is no pricing entry in the right table.

My order by is also not working.  I want to order by product_pricing.PP_CashPrice prior to grouping by.

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM source 
LEFT JOIN product_pricing ON source.Source_ID = product_pricing.Source_ID 
WHERE (product_pricing.Product_ID = '234' 
       OR product_pricing.PP_ID = NULL) 
AND source.Source_Active = 'Yes' 
GROUP by source.Source_ID 
ORDER by PP_CashPrice desc
```

I basically need it to show all sources. The right column will have duplicates but I only need to show the highest one.

My right column is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE product_pricing ( PP_ID int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PP_Type varchar(150) NOT NULL, PP_CashPrice decimal(10,2) NOT NULL, PP_DateObtained date NOT NULL, PP_TimeObtained time NOT NULL, PP_Active varchar(3) NOT NULL, PP_Postcode varchar(150) NOT NULL, Source_ID int(10) NOT NULL, SC_ID int(10) NOT NULL, Product_ID int(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (PP_ID) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What are your results?

Comment: I need it to show all results from source and then add the multiple instances that happen in the product pricing table but then only show the highest price one.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use a where clause on a "Left joined" table. Put the condition in the where clause

I would also use a COALESCE operator for the ordering clause, and probably add an ordering on s.Source_ID if you want different sourceId with "inner pricing" ordering.

```
SELECT * FROM source  s
LEFT JOIN product_pricing pp ON s.Source_ID = pp.Source_ID AND pp.PP_ID = '234'
AND s.Source_Active = 'Yes' 
GROUP by s.Source_ID 
ORDER by s.Source_ID, COALESCE(p.PP_CashPrice, 0) desc
```

Comment: Unfortunately the solution provided shows null values for items that don't have null values.

Comment: @GarethHanda some sample datas, maybe ? By the way, `Select *` and `GROUP BY` one only field is a (bad) Mysql practice...

Comment: Here is my product pricing table:

CREATE TABLE `product_pricing` (
  `PP_ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PP_Type` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `PP_CashPrice` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `PP_DateObtained` date NOT NULL,
  `PP_TimeObtained` time NOT NULL,
  `PP_Active` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `PP_Postcode` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Source_ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `SC_ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Product_ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PP_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;